# Error with C# regex for preventing SQL injection

Tags: c#, mysql, regex, sql-injection

I am trying to create a function that will return true if text does not contain any inputs that might allow SQL injection. I have created a regex pattern with popular database operators.

I am not sure why it does not work?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        bool validQuestionText = validateText("<script>");

        if (validQuestionText == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valid Text");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Text");
        }

    }

    public static bool validateText(string input)
    {
        Regex nonTextRegex = new Regex(@"[^-<>=&%]");

        if (nonTextRegex.IsMatch(input) || input == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Invalid text is always displayed in the console even if I change the string passed to the validateText() method to not contain any characters in the regex expression e.g. pass in "script" instead.

Comment: don't try to roll your own sql injection prevention.

Comment: This regex matches any character except `-<>=&%`, so in "script" it has 6 matches: "s,c,r,i,p,t". Anyhow don't fix it, because what you are doing is really a bad idea anyway.

Comment: there are builtin methods for doing this sort of thing; in addition, using sprocs with params gets around most of the issues

Comment: As said above, don't try to do that, that is very dangerous. Do you know that escaped HTML will bypass that? I strongly suggest you to do not try that

Comment: Properly escaping SQL is a solved problem in basically every language. Don't build SQL via string concatenation. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.

Comment: a 5 second google search got me this: have a look at some ideas how to bypass some brilliant prevention codes like yours: https://blog.netspi.com/sql-injection-death-by-blacklist/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have used parameterized queries but I was trying to add an extra layer of prevention, perhaps that is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

`[^-<>=&%]` means *all characters except `-<>=&%`*.  The `^` at the beginning of the set of characters is a negation in a regex.

But **beware, beware**.  Use bind variables to prevent SQL injection. The set of characters you're trying to exclude don't deal with the stuff that can wreck SQL.

For example, if your query is

```
INSERT INTO logtable (user) VALUES ('$user')
```

and your attacker, by clever parameter formatting, sets `$user` to `bobbytables');DROP TABLE logtable;--`, then your query will say

```
INSERT INTO logtable (user) VALUES ('bobbytables');DROP TABLE logtable;--')
```

and you're pwnd.  Please don't try to do this yourself unless you have a lot of experience. Cybercrooks are smarter and better motivated than we are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used parameter binding but I was trying to add an extra layer of prevention. I will spend more time learning existing solutions rather than trying to create my own.